# Check tic tac toe winner, horizontal and vertical only

Tags: java, arrays, tic-tac-toe

Return X if X has won, O if O has won, and . If neither has one. If null return .. given an 2d array of chars. Don’t check diagonal winners.

Why isn’t this working

```
public char checkBoard(char[][] board){
    if (board != null) {
        for(int i =0; i< 2;i++) {
            if((board[i][0] == board[i][1]) && (board[i][0] == board[i][2]) && (board[i][0] != '.'))
                return board[i][0];
        }

        for(int i =0; i< 2;i++) {
            if((board[0][i] == board[1][i]) && (board[0][i] == board[2][i]) && (board[0][i] != '.'))
                return board[0][i];
        }

    }
    return '.';
}
```

Comment: "It isn't working" is not a meaningful problem statement. Please [edit] your question to include the details of *how* your program isn't working.

Comment: I've thrown a couple sample arrays at your code, and it works fine for me.  Please [edit] your question to include exactly what input you're providing it, and the exected vs actual output.  A [mcve] would be ideal.

Comment: `for(int i =0; i< 2;i++)`. You probably want `i<3` instead

Comment: JClassic you’re the man lol. I had it as board.length before and idk why I changed it, but I didn’t catch that. It worked now ty

Comment: I moved the 2nd If statement into the same loop. Is their any shorter way of checking the winner?